# hook_menu() doesn't work as expected. How can I fix that?

Tags: routes

`hook_menu()` contains the following code.

```
//案件 >　インポート設定 > GMC_Subaccountの追加
$items[FEED_MANAGER_MENU_PATH.'/import/%import_id/gmc_subaccount/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'GMCサブアカウントの追加',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('feed_manager_import_gmc_subaccount_edit', 2),
    'access arguments' => array('feed import gmc_subaccount edit'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
    'file' => 'feed_manager.import_gmc_subaccount.inc',
);
//案件 >　インポート設定 > GMC_Subaccountの編集
$items[FEED_MANAGER_MENU_PATH.'/import/%import_id/gmc_subaccount/%store_id'] = array(
    'title' => 'GMCサブアカウントの編集',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('feed_manager_import_gmc_subaccount_edit', 2, 4),
    'access arguments' => array('feed import gmc_subaccount edit'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'feed_manager.import_gmc_subaccount.inc',
);
```

When I visit /import/%import_id/gmc_subaccount/%store_id, it does't show the edit page, but the list page, which is defined from the following code.

```
//案件 >　インポート設定 > GMC_Subaccount_設定
$items[FEED_MANAGER_MENU_PATH.'/import/%import_id/gmc_subaccount'] = array(
    'title' => 'GMCサブアカウント',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('feed_manager_import_gmc_subaccount_list', 2),
    'access arguments' => array('feed import gmc_subaccount edit'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'feed_manager.import_gmc_subaccount.inc',
);
```

The code I use to create the link to the edit page is the  following.

```
$row['data'][] = l(t('Edit'), FEED_MANAGER_MENU_PATH.'/import/'.$data->import_id.'/gmc_subaccount/'.$data->store_id.'/edit');
```

How can I fix the fact that link shows the wrong page?

Comment: Can you update your second menu item to following and let me know how you go. <pre>
$items[FEED_MANAGER_MENU_PATH.'/import/%import_id/gmc_subaccount/%store_id/edit'] = array( 'title' => 'GMCサブアカウントの編集', 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 'page arguments' => array('feed_manager_import_gmc_subaccount_edit', 2, 4), 'access arguments' => array('feed import gmc_subaccount edit'), 'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION, 'file' => 'feed_manager.import_gmc_subaccount.inc',
);
</pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple problem-

I just added following line to my .module file-

```
function store_id_to_arg($args){
if(empty($args)){ drupal_goto('<front>'); }
return $args;
}
```

Thanks for your help.